# Bugs:Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ios5, xcode4.3

There is an application that we used for testing our IOS app with Facebook integration. It works fine.
We've created a new Facebook application to use as a production one but faced problems in IOS app.
After user have entered login/password, gives the app permissions and press okey - safari show the following error: Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Before run the app please make sure  in the plist.
you are enter correct

1.FacebookAppId

2.URLSchemas